# Problems using Analysis for Office functions

Tags: excel, vba, function, methods, analysis

When we try to run analysis for office functions such as:

lresult = xlApp.Application.Run("SAPLogon", "DS_1", bw_client, bw_user, bw_password)

lresult = xlApp.Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "RefreshData")

Despite analysis add-in is active in our workbook and all macros are enabled (trust center...), we always get the same error: *Cannot run the macro "SAPExecuteCommand". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros are disabled.*

Has anyone any idea to solve this? I´ve tried to add all SAP libraries in Tools/References, however it doesn´t work.

Thank you so much

Comment: How are you creating `xlApp`?

Comment: I use: Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")                                                      I have also run it without the object xlApp since it is launched from an excel macro, but it still doesn´t work: lresult = Application.Run("SAPLogon", "DS_1", bw_client, bw_user, bw_password)

Comment: What's the error message or problem with `lresult = ...`?

Comment: Cannot run the macro "SAPExecuteCommand". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the following registry key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\SapExcelAddIn
```

If the value "LoadBehavior" is set to something different than 3, the described error will occur because the COM Add-In is not loaded. If you set it to 3 ("The Add-In is enabled. If required, users can disable it in the COM Add-In dialog box."), the error should disappear.

See the SAP documentation for details on "LoadBehavior":
https://help.sap.com/viewer/df90d3701aba42b9a4351caa387bd672/LATEST/en-US/f26e8ad16c9b1014bf2c9a7eb0e91070.html